# Media queries and my grid display doesn't work like I want to

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, media-queries

Here is my problem : I put a "main" element and gave him the "grid" display. Then, I wrote 2 ways of how the grid should be in function of the size of the screen, here is what i wrote :

```
main{
    display : grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(400px , auto);
    align-items: stretch;
    margin: 10px;
}
@media screen and (min-width:700px){
    main{
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2 ,1fr);
    }
}
```

So if the size is over 700 px, I have 2 columns and if I have less than 700px, I have 1 column.
The problem is that it doesn't work as you can see in this picture :
[Image of the site when 600px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBUCI.png).
Funny thing is that it only works when the number of pixel is 400 but I also want it to work when it's 700 pixels.

I tried to do the same but instead of using "min-width", using "max-width" but it's the same problem and it shows the exact same site.
Does anybody know where the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

If the size is over 700px, you want 2 columns and if less than 700px, you want 1 column. So you should try in media query 1 column in max-width 700px and 2 columns globally as like:

Try this way, hope your problem will be solved

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(400px , auto);
  align-items: stretch;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px){
  main{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1 ,1fr);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but it does the same thing.